# How can I use IHTMLDocument6 or other IE 8 interfaces from C#?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com-interop

I'm trying to access the `IHTMLDocument6.documentMode` property from my IE BHO, but that interface is not defined in any of the mshtml assemblies I can find on my machine.

I've tried hacking together an interface definition for the interface:

```
[Guid("30510417-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b")]
[TypeLibType(4160)]
public interface IHTMLDocument6
{
    [DispId(1104)]
    float documentMode { get; }
}
```

I can successfully cast the document object to this interface, but I do not get a value that makes sense for the `documentMode` property.

Where can I find the version of mshtml that includes the `IHTMLDocument6` interface, or a correct version of the interface definition to use? Or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use latebinding and do a Type.Invokemember

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx

Comment: `docObj.GetType().InvokeMember("[DispId=1104]", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, docObj, null)` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get Headers and Libs for IE9 from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9759838). If that link becomes broken, I got it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740471.aspx).

You can get interop examples from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/).  It seems pretty thin on MSHTML, but you can add to it once you get it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code to use

```
[Guid("30510417-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IHTMLDocument6
{
    [DispId(1104)]
    object documentMode { get; }
}
```

A `VARIANT` is an `object` in P/Invoke. The above also uses IDispatch which minimizes fuss.